# Concatenate two file with a common pattern but with several lign

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files :

File 1 (sep = tab):

```
A1 bla blo bli 23 blp
A1 bla blo bli 21 blp
A1 bla blo bli 28 blp
B2 bla blo bli 32 blp
B2 bla blo bli 31 blp
B2 bla blo bli 35 blp
```

File 2 (sep = `;`):

```
fli;flo;A1;flu;flc
fli;flo;A2;flu;flc
fli;flo;B1;flu;flc
fli;flo;B2;flu;flc
```

I want to add a list of all values of the 5th (numerical) field in File 1 that correspond to the same value of the 1st field to those lines in File 2 where the 3rd field is the same as that 1st field of File 1. For the above sample input, the desired output would look like this:

```
fli;flo;A1;flu;flc;23;21;28
fli;flo;A2;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B1;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B2;flu;flc;32;31;35
```

Do you have some `awk` command (or else) in order to do that?

I've done some test with `FNR==NR` but nothing close to a start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to the site. When you write "I try to add the different value of each similar pattern" -- can you explain what should be similar to what? It would look like you want to append the last columns of all lines in file1 where the first column is the same as the third column in file2 to that line in file2 ... ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. the similar column between each file are $1 in file 1 and $3 in file2 ( in this example). And your resume is exactly what I try to do, i mean the value in the file 1 are not necessary the last column but in my example yes (i've juste edit the file 1 to be more specific)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish the task with the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR{if ($1 in a) {a[$1]=a[$1] ";" $5} else {a[$1]=$5}} \
            NR>FNR{split($0,f,";"); $0=$0 ";" a[f[3]]; print}' file1 file2
```

(split across 2 lines for better readability).

This will first read `file1`, and while this file is being processed (indicated by `FNR == NR`), create a mapping table `a` that accumulates all `$5` values corresponding to the same `$1` value.

When the second file is being processed (`NR>FNR`), and the table `a` contains an entry for the value of the third semicolon-separated field, that value is appended to the line.

Since it is impossible to specifiy "per-file field separators", the `-F` command-line parameter is chosen to be correct for the first, tab-separated file. This means that when processing the second file, splitting must be performed "by hand", using the `split()` function, with the results stored in another array `f`, whose entries (= fields) are then accessed via `f[number]` instead of `$number`.

(**Update** I stand corrected on that statement by Stalin Vignesh Kumar's answer: it is possible to specify per-file field separators, after all.)

For your sample input, I get

```
fli;flo;A1;flu;flc;23;21;28
fli;flo;A2;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B1;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B2;flu;flc;32;31;35
```

Comment: It's almost perfect, thanks ! It's just that in the final output, I have a return to the line after , like this : `fli;flo;A1;flu;flc\n;23;21;28` do you have a clue why ?

Comment: Was any of the files created/edited under Windows? If so, you may have to run `dos2unix` on them to get the end-of-line characters right.

Comment: You're right ! I'm on linux but I open the file with mobaxterm text editor ... when opened with Atom it's ok . Thanks so much !

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$1]=a[$1]";"$5;next }{sub(";","",a[$3]);print $0";"a[$3]}' file FS=";" file1
fli;flo;A1;flu;flc;23;21;28
fli;flo;A2;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B1;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B2;flu;flc;32;31;35
```

Comment: Good thing pointing out the "per-file FS" possibility. Notice, however, that the OP seems to want a trailing `;` on those lines where no entries in the association table `a` are found (I missed that, too, on my first answer proposal), perhaps you can modify the answer to include that?

Comment: @AdminBee : Included . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] OFS : "") $5; next} {print $0, a[$3]}' OFS=';' file1 FS=';' file2
fli;flo;A1;flu;flc;23;21;28
fli;flo;A2;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B1;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B2;flu;flc;32;31;35
```

Answer (score 1):

File1 (tab separated) is the  first argument and is used to build up the data structure of a hash of array which is indexed by the first field and values are the fifth field(s).

**([bd]?a|[kz])?sh command line:**

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '$"=$,=";";
  @ARGV and
    push(@{$h{$F[0]}}, $F[4]),next;
  my $k = (split $,)[2];
  my $v = "@{$h{$k}}";
  print $_, $v;
' file1 file2
```

**output:**

```
fli;flo;A1;flu;flc;23;21;28
fli;flo;A2;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B1;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B2;flu;flc;32;31;35
```

**Options:**

- `-F` delimiter to split the record on
- `-l` sets RS = ORS = `\n`
- `-a` autosplit record
- `-n` sets up a loop to read the input a record at a time + prints only upon request.
- `-e` Perl code applied to the record.

**Special Variables:**

- `$"`   => list separator
- `$,`   => OFS
- `$_`  => current record
- `@F`  => fields from the current record(0-indexed)
- `@ARGV` => file arguments array. The file being read is removed from this array, so we can use it's count to keep track of which file is being handled.

Answer (score 0):

The `BEGIN` block creates an array with the prefix for each `$1` value built from the `$5` values.

The line code

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { while ( (getline <"input.1") > 0) { a[$1]=a[$1] ";" $5; }; FS=";" }; '\
'{ if (a[$3]=="") a[$3]=";"; print $0 a[$3]; }' input.2

fli;flo;A1;flu;flc;23;21;28
fli;flo;A2;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B1;flu;flc;
fli;flo;B2;flu;flc;32;31;35
```

Comment: That will spin off into an infinite loop if/when getline fails and returns a negative number. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for if/when/how to call getline.